# What are Search, Control Specific and Generic in Coded UI Test Builder

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

In the Coded UI Test Builder, when I select a control, in the right panel there are 3 categories of properties for the control: Search, Control Specific and Generic:

[image]

What is the difference between them? I know I can use the properties in the Search section in my Coded UI tests, but can use the properties in the Control Specific and Generic section as well?

Answer (score 1):

They're just categories of properties related to the object you're currently looking at, and they're aptly organized based on properties that are good for searching, others that are specific to the type of control you're looking at (example, `HtmlHyperlink` will be the only type of control that has an `href` property), and the Generic section is a list of properties that exist across the technology type (WinControl, HtmlControl, WpfControl).

Personally, I like to use the search properties and control-specific properties the most, as they tend to be more meaningful for a readability standpoint, and return fewer failures.  If you search for your HtmlComboBox by adding its ID and control type, you'll find it easily.